# Cannot post data in android using webservice

Tags: android, web-services

Following are the code snipets I am trying to execute but I am getting FatalErrorException but when I try to run webservice code using url in browser

```
http://localhost:8082/WebServices/Rest/courseService/LoginInfo/a:a
```

it runs perfectly and gives perfect result but I cannot do the same with android using below code

I have this ServiceHandlerClass which will handle all webservice request

```
public class ServiceHandler {
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    // Default Constructor
    public ServiceHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, String parameter) {

        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (parameter != null) {
                    url += parameter;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                Log.d("Parmaeter2",parameter);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        }  catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Service Handler Error",e.toString());
        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

But I am getting error on `httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

```
This is my async DoInbackground code

    class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET,ParameterToPass);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            //PojoProduct item = null;
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        msg = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            } else {

            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(!msg.equals("false"))
            {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("Username", txtUserName.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.putString("Password", txtPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.commit();

                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Category.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                //System.out.println("Successful");
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SuccessFul", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                txtUserName.setText("");
                txtPassword.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please Enter Valid UserName & Password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Following is the error

```
04-10 03:30:44.850: E/AndroidRuntime(5559): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
04-10 03:30:44.850: E/AndroidRuntime(5559):     at com.example.shoponchat.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is deprecated , it would be best practice if u start to use HttpURLConnection ..
I am providing code which may help u to understand how to use HttpURLConnection ..
Ask me if u require any other info :)

```
        private class GetUsers extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {

    String url_ = "Provide url here";
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
            String urlParameters = "username="
                    + URLEncoder
                            .encode(userInfo.getString("username", "Null"),
                                    "UTF-8");
            writer.write(urlParameters);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + '\n');
                }

                String jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
                System.out.println(jsonString);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

                return "User List Loaded succesfully";

            } else {

                return "Error occured in Registration";

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception2");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception3");
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return "Null";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String[] names = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String username = jsonObject.getString("username");
                names[i] = username;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Json array exception");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend on using HTTPClient any more, since it is not supported any more from sdk version 23.

So, it will be better to migrate the network operations to URL Connection.

I have created a NetworkOps Util. You can take a look on that, whether it may be any use for you :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.csehelper.variables.Constants;
import com.csehelper.variables.Keys;
import com.csehelper.variables.Url;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NetworkOps {
    public final String EXCEPTION = "~Exception~";
    /****************************
     * Method to Grab Source
     ****************************/
    public static String GrabSource(String URL) {
        return PostData(URL, null);
    }



    /**
     * *****************************************
     * Method to Grab Source code from URL
     * Posting Data
     * *****************************************
     */
    private static String PostData(String url, Uri.Builder uribuilder) {
        String Source;
       HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            if(uribuilder != null) {
                String query = uribuilder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }

            urlConnection.connect();

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                String line;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                Source = builder.toString();
            } else {
                Source = EXCEPTION + "Server unreachable. Check network connection.";
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + "Connection timed out.";
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + Constants.EXCEPTION_NO_NET;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + "Server error";
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + "Protocol error";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + "Server unreachable. Check network connection.";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Source = EXCEPTION + "Error:" + e.toString() + " - "
                    + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return Source;
    }


}
```

Call these Static Functions from AsyncTask:

```
/*********************************
 * AsyncTask to GrabSource
 ********************************/
class AsyncTask_GrabSource extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String Source = null;
    String url = "https://enigmatic-woodland-35608.herokuapp.com/pager.json";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       //Runs on Main Thread. You can access your UI elements here.
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Don't access any UI elements from this function
        Source = NetworkOps.GrabSource(this.url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (Source != null) {
            if (!Source.contains("~Exception~")) {
                //Show Error Message or do whatever you want
            } else {
                //Do Whatever with your Grabbed Sourcecode.
                // This function runs on UI Thread, so you can update UI elements here
            }

    }
}
```

You can also post data with the function PostData. In method doInBackground, add this:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("key", "value")
                    .appendQueryParameter("key2", "value2");

Source = NetworkOps.PostData(getApplicationContext(), url, builder);
```

Am not sure localhost:8080 is accessible through android